# maximize product of two numbers formed with the digits $1$ to $9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You are given the digits from $1$ to $9$. You can form two numbers by concatenating them, for example, $975123$ and $864$, and then take the product of the two resulting numbers. Find how to maximize the product.

To give you a hint, the answer is $87531\cdot9642$.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply try them all.  Since the digits should be listed in decreasing order from left to right, there are only 512 possibilities to check.  In Mathematica,

```
possibilities = Map[FromDigits[Reverse[#]] &,
  {#, Complement[Range[9], #]} & /@ Subsets[Range[9]], {2}];
First[Reverse[SortBy[{#, Times @@ #} & /@ possibilities, Last]]]
```

{{87531, 9642}, 843973902}

Comment: surely I wanted an analytic solution. :)

Comment: Well, the problem looks very Project Euler-ish where the objective is to find a solution using a combination of programming and cleverness.

Comment: I agree. But the result looks very informative in the sense that there is some rule here. But I am not sure how to formulate.